# Passing UILocalNotification information from AppDelegate to a View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalnotification

I'm storing the title of one of my items in my Table View Controller in `UILocalNotification.userInfo`. When the notification appears I'd like to be able to jump to this item.

What's the best practice to do this? I extract the title from `UILocalNotification.userInfo`in the AppDelegate's

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleActionWithIdentifier identifier: String?, forLocalNotification notification: UILocalNotification, completionHandler: () -> Void)
```

Once i've extracted it inside this function how do I pass the title to the Table View Controller? What's the best practice?

Comment: Create `object` or particular class and pass data to that `Viewcontroller` and write required code in `ViewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you structure the app. For example, if each table view cell is associated with an `itemId` in your database, you can pass this `itemId` to your view controller, then programatically create a view controller that would have been pushed in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, then pushing that at `viewDidLoad`.